# PHP+jQuery is preventing my select element from updating

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using PHP to show years between 1940 and the current year and using a `foreach` loop to render each `option` inside a `select` element. Everything works as planned until I add an `id` to the `select` element that a block of jquery looks at for changes.

Essentially I am trying to `console.log` (for now) the value of whatever `option` gets selected but something about my jQuery/PHP is stopping the `select` from displaying the selected option. The `console.log` works as expected but the selected option doesn't update in the element. It always goes back to displaying the default option aka 2018 since it's the current year.

If I change the PHP `foreach` select/option to a static dropdown of plain HTML it works fine. Likewise, if I disconnect the jQuery but keep the PHP dynamically generated `option` list it works fine. Something about the combo of my PHP+jQuery is preventing the `select` from updating and I cannot figure what.

Here is my HTML/PHP code:

```
<select name="birthyear" id="birthyear">
  <?php
    // $years is setting the range from current year to 1940
    $years = range(date('Y'), 1940);
    foreach ($years as $year) {
      echo "<option id='$year' value='$year'>".$year."</option>";
    }
  ?>
</select>
```

Here is my jQuery:

```
$('#birthyear').on('change', function() {
  var date = new Date();
  var year = date.getFullYear();
  var yearsOld = year - $(this).val();

  console.log(yearsOld + " years old.");

  if (yearsOld >= 18) {
    console.log("age >= 18")
  } else {
    console.log("You aren't old enough!");
  }
});
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: because you are not actually updating it. you are just logging to console. nothing more.

Comment: Can you show us the generated markup, not the script that generates the markup?  javascript doesn't care how the markup is generated.  just what the markup is that it is going to work with.

Comment: The PHP is irrelevant here. Post a [mcve] showing the rendered output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine... All I did was execute the PHP to get the HTML and then plugged it into JSFiddle.

I'd assume your problem is that you didn't properly include jQuery.

```
<select name="birthyear" id="birthyear">
    <option id='2018' value='2018'>2018</option>
    <option id='2017' value='2017'>2017</option>
    <option id='2016' value='2016'>2016</option>
    <option id='2015' value='2015'>2015</option>
    <option id='2014' value='2014'>2014</option>
    <option id='2013' value='2013'>2013</option>
    <option id='2012' value='2012'>2012</option>
    <option id='2011' value='2011'>2011</option>
    <option id='2010' value='2010'>2010</option>
    <option id='2009' value='2009'>2009</option>
    <option id='2008' value='2008'>2008</option>
    <option id='2007' value='2007'>2007</option>
    <option id='2006' value='2006'>2006</option>
    <option id='2005' value='2005'>2005</option>
    <option id='2004' value='2004'>2004</option>
    <option id='2003' value='2003'>2003</option>
    <option id='2002' value='2002'>2002</option>
    <option id='2001' value='2001'>2001</option>
    <option id='2000' value='2000'>2000</option>
    <option id='1999' value='1999'>1999</option>
    <option id='1998' value='1998'>1998</option>
    <option id='1997' value='1997'>1997</option>
    <option id='1996' value='1996'>1996</option>
    <option id='1995' value='1995'>1995</option>
    <option id='1994' value='1994'>1994</option>
    <option id='1993' value='1993'>1993</option>
    <option id='1992' value='1992'>1992</option>
    <option id='1991' value='1991'>1991</option>
    <option id='1990' value='1990'>1990</option>
    <option id='1989' value='1989'>1989</option>
    <option id='1988' value='1988'>1988</option>
    <option id='1987' value='1987'>1987</option>
    <option id='1986' value='1986'>1986</option>
    <option id='1985' value='1985'>1985</option>
    <option id='1984' value='1984'>1984</option>
    <option id='1983' value='1983'>1983</option>
    <option id='1982' value='1982'>1982</option>
    <option id='1981' value='1981'>1981</option>
    <option id='1980' value='1980'>1980</option>
    <option id='1979' value='1979'>1979</option>
    <option id='1978' value='1978'>1978</option>
    <option id='1977' value='1977'>1977</option>
    <option id='1976' value='1976'>1976</option>
    <option id='1975' value='1975'>1975</option>
    <option id='1974' value='1974'>1974</option>
    <option id='1973' value='1973'>1973</option>
    <option id='1972' value='1972'>1972</option>
    <option id='1971' value='1971'>1971</option>
    <option id='1970' value='1970'>1970</option>
    <option id='1969' value='1969'>1969</option>
    <option id='1968' value='1968'>1968</option>
    <option id='1967' value='1967'>1967</option>
    <option id='1966' value='1966'>1966</option>
    <option id='1965' value='1965'>1965</option>
    <option id='1964' value='1964'>1964</option>
    <option id='1963' value='1963'>1963</option>
    <option id='1962' value='1962'>1962</option>
    <option id='1961' value='1961'>1961</option>
    <option id='1960' value='1960'>1960</option>
    <option id='1959' value='1959'>1959</option>
    <option id='1958' value='1958'>1958</option>
    <option id='1957' value='1957'>1957</option>
    <option id='1956' value='1956'>1956</option>
    <option id='1955' value='1955'>1955</option>
    <option id='1954' value='1954'>1954</option>
    <option id='1953' value='1953'>1953</option>
    <option id='1952' value='1952'>1952</option>
    <option id='1951' value='1951'>1951</option>
    <option id='1950' value='1950'>1950</option>
    <option id='1949' value='1949'>1949</option>
    <option id='1948' value='1948'>1948</option>
    <option id='1947' value='1947'>1947</option>
    <option id='1946' value='1946'>1946</option>
    <option id='1945' value='1945'>1945</option>
    <option id='1944' value='1944'>1944</option>
    <option id='1943' value='1943'>1943</option>
    <option id='1942' value='1942'>1942</option>
    <option id='1941' value='1941'>1941</option>
    <option id='1940' value='1940'>1940</option>
</select>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gpfh150g/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You were right, the code itself is sound. I tried it in Safari/Firefox and it worked perfectly. I just tried it in Chrome Incognito mode and that worked so it must be an issue with my Chrome. Thanks for the help.